# What is causing this error when loading in music with LibGDX?

Tags: java, android, libgdx, audio

I am following a tutorial on how to code a Mario game with Brent Aureli and LibGDX. On this part ([video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fcAogRcLvW8&index=15&list=PLZm85UZQLd2SXQzsF-a0-pPF6IWDDdrXt)) we started on using sound. Here is a shorted version of the code I'm using:

```
 public static AssetManager manager;

@Override
public void create () {
    manager = new AssetManager();
    manager.load("mario_music.ogg", Music.class);
    manager.finishLoading();

    setScreen(new PlayScreen(this));
}
```

I have the "mario_music.ogg" in the right folder and named correctly (android/assets/mario_music.ogg) , yet I get this super long error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 19364
              Process: com.davidheadrick.mariogame, PID: 12739
              com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Couldn't load dependencies of asset: mario_music.ogg
                  at com.badlogic.gdx.assets.AssetManager.handleTaskError(AssetManager.java:570)
                  at com.badlogic.gdx.assets.AssetManager.update(AssetManager.java:375)
                  at com.badlogic.gdx.assets.AssetManager.finishLoading(AssetManager.java:396)
                  at com.davidheadrick.mariogame.MarioGame.create(MarioGame.java:38)
                  at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphics.onSurfaceChanged(AndroidGraphics.java:275)
                  at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1550)
                  at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1278)
               Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Couldn't load dependencies of asset: mario_music.ogg
                  at com.badlogic.gdx.assets.AssetLoadingTask.handleAsyncLoader(AssetLoadingTask.java:121)
                  at com.badlogic.gdx.assets.AssetLoadingTask.update(AssetLoadingTask.java:90)
                  at com.badlogic.gdx.assets.AssetManager.updateTask(AssetManager.java:498)
                  at com.badlogic.gdx.assets.AssetManager.update(AssetManager.java:373)
                  at com.badlogic.gdx.assets.AssetManager.finishLoading(AssetManager.java:396) 
                  at com.davidheadrick.mariogame.MarioGame.create(MarioGame.java:38) 
                  at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphics.onSurfaceChanged(AndroidGraphics.java:275) 
                  at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1550) 
                  at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1278) 
               Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Error loading audio file: mario_music.ogg
              Note: Internal audio files must be placed in the assets directory.
                  at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.async.AsyncResult.get(AsyncResult.java:46)
                  at com.badlogic.gdx.assets.AssetLoadingTask.handleAsyncLoader(AssetLoadingTask.java:119)
                    ... 8 more
               Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Error loading audio file: mario_music.ogg
              Note: Internal audio files must be placed in the assets directory.
                  at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidAudio.newMusic(AndroidAudio.java:120)
                  at com.badlogic.gdx.assets.loaders.MusicLoader.loadAsync(MusicLoader.java:48)
                  at com.badlogic.gdx.assets.loaders.MusicLoader.loadAsync(MusicLoader.java:29)
                  at com.badlogic.gdx.assets.AssetLoadingTask.call(AssetLoadingTask.java:70)
                  at com.badlogic.gdx.assets.AssetLoadingTask.call(AssetLoadingTask.java:34)
                  at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.async.AsyncExecutor$2.call(AsyncExecutor.java:58)
                  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
                  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
               Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: This file can not be opened as a file descriptor; it is probably compressed
                  at android.content.res.AssetManager.openAssetFd(Native Method)
                  at android.content.res.AssetManager.openFd(AssetManager.java:346)
                  at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidFileHandle.getAssetFileDescriptor(AndroidFileHandle.java:237)
                  at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidAudio.newMusic(AndroidAudio.java:110)
                  at com.badlogic.gdx.assets.loaders.MusicLoader.loadAsync(MusicLoader.java:48) 
                  at com.badlogic.gdx.assets.loaders.MusicLoader.loadAsync(MusicLoader.java:29) 
                  at com.badlogic.gdx.assets.AssetLoadingTask.call(AssetLoadingTask.java:70) 
                  at com.badlogic.gdx.assets.AssetLoadingTask.call(AssetLoadingTask.java:34) 
                  at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.async.AsyncExecutor$2.call(AsyncExecutor.java:58) 
                  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237) 
                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) 
                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) 
                  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

I have no idea why it could be doing this as I'm using the same music file he's using in the tutorial. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried to put your file somewhere in core/assets?

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be the ("_") that you're using in your file path is the PROBLEM!. had the same problem, it seams that you cannot use Upercase letters and regular regexes and of course [special chars](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html)

and check if you are specifying the path correctly. like when you declare:
`manager.load("mario_music.ogg", Music.class);`

the asset is located in the root folder in :
android/assets/